# Can Views output "raw" text field data?

Tags: views

I have a view that shows the **Body** field of several book pages.  The text format for these pages includes the [Markdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown) filter.

I want to export the body field data as the original markdown without processing it into HTML.  (This is an admin-only view that I want to use to collect the markdown-formatted text from several book pages to make an ebook.)

Is there an option within the Views module to output the "unprocessed" markdown?

Comment: Did you try the rewrite field with the {{ *_raw }} token?

Comment: @cchen How do I do that? I just tried going into the field and setting **Rewrite results** to `{{ *_raw }}` or  `{{ body_raw }}`, but neither worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Under the **Rewrite results > Override the output of this field with custom text** option, one of the Twig tokens you can use is `{{ $FIELD_NAME__value }}` (e.g. `{{ body__value }}`). This will have views render the field in its raw, pre-filtered, format.